# How to close the database connection at the end of the program?

Tags: java, jdbc, resources

In a Java program, I have a singleton class that holds the database connection, which is used by the entire program.

How do I tell Java to close the connection when the program ends?

I can put a connection.close() statement at the end of main, but this will not be executed if the program ends unexpectedly, e.g, by an uncaught exception or "exit" call somewhere within the program. How do I tell Java to close the connection regardless of how the program ends?

Comment: you shouldn't wait until the end of the application to close your resource.

Comment: why don't you put it in finally block?

Comment: Don't leave the connection open.  Open a connection, do your business, and then return it to the connection pool.  Imagine being at a party with a keg of beer and only 5 cups.  Yeah, you better put your cup back so I can drink too.

Comment: @Aman this does not handle procedures calling "System.exit"...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe not the best metaphor, since from his perspective, he 'd better keep the cup ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I only need one db connection in my application. Why should I close it and open it each time I need to do something?

Comment: Because it puts a strain on your DB.  Maybe it doesn't matter now, but down the road your app may be running on several nodes in the cloud, each of which is hitting the DB.  And other processes may also be using the same database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [a VM shutdown hook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) if the method `System.exit` might be called.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> closeDatabaseConnection()));
```

Shutdown hooks also will be called if the program exits normally:

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the `System.exit` method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing `^C`, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

But there is no guarantee they will be run if something unexpected happens:

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the `SIGKILL` signal on Unix or the `TerminateProcess` call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. **If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.**