# How to listen for OutOfMemoryError and exit the JVM

Tags: java, java-8, out-of-memory

Is there a way to build a global `OutOfMemoryError` Listener for my Java app?

I want to stop the JVM gracefully (`try-catch` is not an option) on OOM.

Comment: I think you'll find that the JVM exits all by itself on an OOM error.

Comment: are you trying to utilize meltdown attack?

Comment: actually my app not stop on OOM, that why I come here for help :)

Comment: If your app doesn't stop on OOM you (or a library) is catching it (and probably printing some message or you wouldn't know). Add some details about your actual problem, maybe there is a solution

Comment: what did you mean by *"to stop the JVM gracefully"*? `OutOfMemoryError`, an `Error`, indicates serious problems you can't handle reasonably. But you can perform some actions before it shuts down by [registering a JVM shutdown hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110957/4922375).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [JVM option](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="<cmd args>; <cmd args>"
```

and execute command of your choice

Answer (score 8):

Since an `OutOfMemoryError` is normally not caught, one of the simplest approaches would be

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread,t) -> {
    if(t instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
});
```

But in some cases, like actions executed via an `ExecutorService`, all throwables get caught automatically. Still, in these cases, there should be some code in your application evaluating the result and handling exceptional cases anyway.

But perhaps, you want to react *before* it is to late, e.g. to save pending data before there isn’t even enough memory to do that. A solution for that would go into the following direction:

```
MemoryMXBean mBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
((NotificationEmitter)mBean).addNotificationListener(
    (n, mb) -> {
        MemoryUsage mu = ((MemoryMXBean)mb).getHeapMemoryUsage();
        if(mu.getUsed()*100/mu.getMax() > 80)
            System.out.println("more than 80% used");// may initiate a shut down
    },
    n -> n.getType().equals(MemoryNotificationInfo.MEMORY_COLLECTION_THRESHOLD_EXCEEDED),
    mBean);

for(MemoryPoolMXBean pool : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {
    if(pool.getType() == MemoryType.HEAP && pool.isCollectionUsageThresholdSupported()) {
        pool.setCollectionUsageThreshold((int)Math.floor(pool.getUsage().getMax()*0.8));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to simply receive a notification when the total heap usage exceeds a threshold, hence, we have to install a threshold on each memory pool supporting it (usually the tenured generation) and re-check the total usage on notification, to trigger a shutdown when the total usage exceeds a threshold.

Comment: we have a tool like this, killings VMs and starting new ones when they hit a certain amount of heap percentage, I had no idea how that is done, thank you for the hints

Answer (score 5):

There is also the [ExitOnOutOfMemoryError option](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138745) used as a JVM command line option.

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError
```

> ExitOnOutOfMemoryError - When you enable this option, the JVM exits on the first occurrence of an out-of-memory error. It can be used if you prefer restarting an instance of the JVM rather than handling out of memory errors.

It's not really a *graceful* JVM exit, I don't think shutdown hooks run.